# Slope interpretation of a log model?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics

Why does a 1 unit change in $x$ in the following model equal to a $100\beta_2$% change in $y$?

$$\ln(y)=\beta_1 + \beta_2x$$

I know how to find the derivative  but my statistics textbook gives this alternative interpretation and I don't know why it holds.

Comment: May I know which statistics textbook do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in $y$ should be

\begin{align}\frac{e^{\beta_1+\beta_2 (x+1)}-e^{\beta_1+\beta_2 (x)}}{e^{\beta_1+\beta_2 (x)}} \times 100 \% &=(e^{\beta_2}-1)\times 100\%\\
&=(\beta_2 + \frac{\beta_2^2}2+\ldots )\times 100 \%\end{align}

The approximation requires $\beta$ to be small.